# How to upload file via Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to upload files from android device to the server using retrofit.

But every time, it results with `no` in the console.

*FilesApi.java*:

```java
public interface FilesApi {
    @Multipart
    @POST("file")
    Call<String> storeFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
}
```

In *MainActivity.java*:

```java
private void uploadFile(){
     RequestBody requestFile= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),file);
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);


    //RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),file);
    FilesApi api = RetrofitService.createService(FilesApi.class);
    api.storeFile(body).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP code:

```php
<?php 
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
{
    echo "YESS";
}
else
{
    echo "no";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Filename should be the same on the Retrofit Parameter as well on the Server Key.

Please refer this link for complete guidance.
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-upload-file-tutorial/